# Parse csv to json then Inject data into javascript file with Gulp

Tags: javascript, json, csv, gulp

I have CSV data that I need to convert to JSON then inject into a script.  I have a partially working solution, but it injects `[object, object]` rather than the actual json data into my final script.

The response should be an array of objects (and appears to be when I log the data to the console).  If I do a `typeof` test on data it returns `object`.

## Update:

`gulp-replace` must be replacing one string with another, which would explain why i'm getting `[Object object]`.  I'll need to find another way to inject the JSON.

I tried using `gulp-preprocess`, but got the same result with `[Object object]` in my output folder.

**Gulpfile**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var replace = require('gulp-replace');
var Converter = require("csvtojson").Converter;
var converter = new Converter({});

// Read data.csv, parse to JSON
gulp.task('replace', function() {
  require("fs").createReadStream("./data.csv").pipe(converter);
  converter.on("end_parsed", injectJSON);
});

// Inject JSON into script.js
function injectJSON(json) {
  return gulp.src('src/script.js')
    .pipe(replace('[\'json\']', json))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('js'));
}

gulp.task('default', ['replace']);
```

**Script**

```
(function () {
  var permits = ['json']; // <- replace this with JSON data
})();
```

**Output**

```
(function () {
  var permits = [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]...
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to `stringify` what you're injecting:

```
function injectJSON(json) {
  return gulp.src('src/script.js')
    .pipe(replace("['json']", JSON.stringify(json)))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('js'));
}
```